# Flutter FirebaseAuth not sending verification code to phone

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add a feature on my app that allows users to verify their phone number by sending a code to their phone numbers. I found that I can do that by using firebase. This is how I send verification code:

```
 Future<void> verifyPhone() async {
void verificationCompleted(AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
  print('verificationCompleted $phoneAuthCredential');
  _phoneAuthCredential = phoneAuthCredential;
  _db.updateUserField(userUid, {
    'isNumberConfirmed': true,
    'linkedAccounts': FieldValue.arrayUnion(['P-$phoneAuthCredential'])
  });
  currentUser.isNumberConfirmed = true;
  currentUser.linkedAccounts.add('P-$phoneAuthCredential');
  worked = true;
}

void verificationFailed(FirebaseAuthException error) {
  worked = false;
}

void codeSent(String verificationId, [int code]) {
  _code = code;
  _verificationId = verificationId;
  print('Code: $code\t_verificationId: $_verificationId');
}

void codeAutoRetrievalTimeout(String verificationId) {
  worked = false;
}

_auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: '+1${currentUser.phone}',
    timeout: Duration(milliseconds: 60000),
    verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
    verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
    codeSent: codeSent,
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
```

}

but whenever this method get called, I get the following messages and no verification code is sent:

```
I/BiChannelGoogleApi(25924): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@bafccce
W/DynamiteModule(25924): Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/FirebaseAuth(25924): [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
```

I'm not sure why it is not sending the code. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please share more code for sign in and verification , without that we can't help you.

Comment: @gladiator I added the full method code.

Answer (score 0):

I find your code hard to debug so I am sharing this :

First make sure you have enabled phone sign in method in  firebase console ,
and added Firebase Authentication plugin and Firebase core plugin in `pubspec.yaml`

define your verify phone number button like this :

```
onPressed: (){
                        //code for sign in
                        final mobile = _phoneTextBoxController.text.trim();
                        registerUser(mobile, context);
                    }
```

Now define whole verifying process like this :

```
Future registerUser(String mobile, BuildContext context) async{

  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  
  _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: mobile,
    timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
    verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential authCredential){
_auth.signInWithCredential(_credential).then((AuthResult result){
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => HomeScreen(result.user)
  ));
}).catchError((e){
  print(e);
});
},
verificationFailed: (AuthException authException){
  print(authException.message);
},
codeSent:(String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]){
  //show dialog to take input from the user
  showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
    title: Text("Enter SMS Code"),
    content: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        TextField(
          controller: _codeController,
        ),

      ],
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      FlatButton(
        child: Text("Done"),
        textColor: Colors.white,
        color: Colors.redAccent,
        onPressed: () {
          FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
          
          smsCode = _codeController.text.trim();
          
          _credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: smsCode);
          auth.signInWithCredential(_credential).then((AuthResult result){
            Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HomeScreen(result.user)
            ));
          }).catchError((e){
            print(e);
          });
        },
      )
    ],
  )
);
},
codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId){
  verificationId = verificationId;
  print(verificationId);
  print("Timout");
}
);
```

So what above code does ? First it sends the OTP code to user and  try to sign in using this code :

```
verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential authCredential){
_auth.signInWithCredential(_credential).then((AuthResult result){
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => HomeScreen(result.user)
  ));
}).catchError((e){
  print(e);
});
},
```

and pushes user to the home screen , you can change above code accordingly to match your app home screen . If  auto retrieval fails then the `codeSent :`  shows user a `showDialog` to manually enter the code . For more information visit [this](https://medium.com/flutterpub/firebase-user-authentication-using-phone-verification-in-flutter-c34dc0f7a9f8) medium article and for complete code visit [this](https://github.com/themaaz32/firebase_user_login) github repository

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify this. This is just a temp value to showcase that I'm passing a phone number

Comment: Please share more  code for sign in and verification , without that we can't help you.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I still didn't test it yet, I got quite busy these days.